# how I save dynamically created Labels and Checkboxes values into sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how I save dynamically created Labels and Checkboxes values into sql server

```
 protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;

            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }  
    }

 protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Event(EventName,StartDate,EventDuration,StartTime,EndTime,SlotDuration) output inserted.EventId values(@EventName,@StartDate,@EventDuration,@StartTime,@EndTime,@SlotDuration)", con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", EventName_TB.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate_TB.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDuration", EventDuration_DDL.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", StartTime_DDL.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", EndTime_DDL.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlotDuration", SlotDuration_DDL.Text);
        Int32 id = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

        var label = Labeldiv.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        var checkbox = Labeldiv.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con))
        {
             int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
             {
                 var paramDay = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                 var paramStatus = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventStatus", SqlDbType.Int);

                     paramDay.Value = label.Text;
                     paramStatus.Value = checkbox.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                     cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

             }
        }
        con.Close();  
    }
```

I have created Labels and CheckBoxes dynamically in EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged.

now I want to save these values into sql server in Wizard1_FinishButtonClick.

how I save dynamically created Labels and Checkboxes values into sql server

.
.
.
.
..

Comment: It's my understanding that label values are not persisted in the `ViewState` so it might be prudent to move away from using labels for storing data. `asp:HiddenField` or `input` elements with `display:none` would be better practice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to save dynamically created Checkboxes values into sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242135/how-to-save-dynamically-created-checkboxes-values-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You have to recreate those dynamically created labels and check boxes for the button click as well, because when the user clicks the finish button, that causes a post back to the server and the page is recreated, but the dynamic label and check box logic is not executed, thus your database saving logic cannot "find" these controls.

I recommend moving your dynamic label and check box creation logic to a separate method that can be called by the `EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged()` and `Wizard1_FinishButtonClick()`, like this:

```
private void BuildDynamicControls()
{
    int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Label NewLabel = new Label();
        NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
        var eventDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
        NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

        CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
        newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;

        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    }  
}
```

Now in your event handlers, you can call this method, like this:

```
protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildDynamicControls();
}

protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    BuildDynamicControls();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can call `BuildDynamicControls()` in the `Page_Load`. This takes care of other buttons on the page destroying the values when they cause a post back, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do other page load logic here

    BuildDynamicControls();
}
```

> Note: If you go this route, then you will not need to call `BuildDynamicControls()` in the `EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged()` or `Wizard1_FinishButtonClick()` methods, because the `Page_Load` happens before either of those events in the page life-cycle.

Comment: @THOR - The `SqlCommand` is in the `Wizard1_FinishButtonClick()` just like in your posted code. I am not recommending to change any of your database interaction logic.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244390/how-to-write-the-checked-change-event-for-dynamically-created-checkbox